# movies.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started learning React and I am getting this error don't know how to fix I have searched alot about this problem but can't find anything useful. Please help!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const MovieList = () => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = ([
        {
            name: 'Harry Potter',
            price: '$10',
            id: 23124
        },
        {
            name: 'Game of Thrones',
            price: '$10',
            id: 2566124
        },
        {
            name: 'Inception',
            price: '$10',
            id: 23524
        }
    ]);

    return (
        <div>
        {movies.map(movie => (
            <li>{movie.name}</li>
        ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `useState` call here

Comment: You're assigning a single object to `movies`.

Comment: yup, change line 4 to `const [movies, setMovies] = useState([` and that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are importing useState

`import React, {useState} from 'react';`

You arent calling it anywhere.

For this code to be working change the following line

```
const [movies, setMovies] = ([
```

to

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([
```

Its simple as that :-)

You can find more here [React Hooks overview](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)

I am just learning React myself and have been looking into Hooks recently.

Comment: I am getting a similar error in other app aswell can you specify what's wrong with that?